# How to display SELECTED value in ion-option

Tags: angular6, ionic4

I have a generic ion-option, but I want to display the value was selected from the list. instead of the 3 points  ( ... ) 
          
            V1
            V2

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-select ok-text="Choisir" [(ngModel)]="val" cancel-text="Annuler" >
    <ion-select-option value="Y">Y</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="X">X</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```